# How to Calculate number of graphs exists in page and how to take tooltips of each graph using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have multiple drop-downs in my page and multiple radio buttons available in my web page. Based on the selection of drop-downs and radio buttons the data will change. I need to automate this process and i need to take the tool tips of each graph data.

Kindly help me if any one have idea?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have selected the radio buttons and drop downs through python selenium. I am stucked with how to calcualte the number of  bars are there in graph and i need to take each bar tool tip